# How to remove all double quotes from json key values using php?

Tags: php, json

I got a json data. I want to remove all double quotes from json keys so I be able to parse the data that I want. My current code works well if there is no double quote on any key but as soon as there is A double quote in a key then my code doesn't parse the json data! could any one tell me how to fix this problem.Thanks

```
$code = stripslashes($_POST['outputtext']);
$data = json_decode($code, false);


foreach($data->videos as $item) {

   echo "<br>id: ".$item->id . "\n";
   echo "<br>title: ".$item->title . "\n";
   echo "<br>url: ".$item->url . "\n";
   echo "<br>img: ".$item->img . "\n";
   echo "<br>img: ".$item->description . "\n";
   echo "<br>";

}
```

JSON data:

```
{
   "cat":{
      "id":"1234567",
      "source_id":null,
      "title_en":"first season",
      "description_en":"This is spring category "
   },
   "videos":[
      {
         "id":"312412343",
         "url":"\/2015-07-17\/1abcd.mp4",
         "img":"image\/44\/\/2015-07-17\/1abcd.jpg",
         "title":"first "title" here",
         "description":"some text" for description "here "
      },
      {
         "id":"2342343",
         "url":"\/2015-07-16\/2dcdeg.mp4",
         "img":"images\/44\/\/2015-07-16\/2dcdeg.jpg",
         "title":"second "title "here",
         "description":"some text" for description "here "
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply .I know it is not valid that is the way i receive it via api so i want to validate it (by removing extra double quotes but don't know how) and parse it!

Comment: This needs to be fixed from the api provider, you can create regular expression and replace the double quotes by using some tricky logic from JSON string and then apply JSON encode. Although the better approach is to receive a Valid JSON.

Comment: Please include the error details in your question.

Comment: Afshan Shujat how i can use reglar expression to get data between ":" and ",? I want get those data then use str_replace('"',"",$text);